How to Implement FIFO Matching for Buy and Sell Transactions in SQL
I have a table in SQL that tracks stock trading transactions with the following columns:
date: Date of the transaction
id: Unique identifier for the transaction
ticker: Stock ticker symbol
txn_type: Transaction type ('Buy' or 'Sell')
qty: Quantity of shares
price_per_share: Price per share
example table:



Date
id
ticker
txn type
qty
price per share




1/1/2024
1
ABC
Buy
10
100


2/1/2024
2
ABC
Sell
5
105


3/1/2024
3
ABC
Buy
3
90


4/1/2024
4
ABC
Buy
15
85


5/1/2024
5
ABC
Sell
10
103



I need to match each sell qty with the corresponding buy qty in a FIFO (First-In-First-Out) manner.
Expected output:



Date
id
ticker
txn type
sell_qty
Buy_id
price per share




1/1/2024
2
ABC
Sell
5
1
100


2/1/2024
5
ABC
Sell
5
1
100


3/1/2024
5
ABC
Sell
3
3
90


4/1/2024
5
ABC
Sell
2
4
85



Iam unable to make this using SQL query.
COuld anyone help me to develop SQL query for the above problem?

You have to choose one of mysql, sql-server or sqlite

Your date format is ambiguous, is 1/2/2024 before or after 2/1/2024? (YYYY-MM-DD is the universal, ISO 8601 and ISO 9075 format.)

@siggemannen I prefer my sql.

@jarih, I just provided a sample example table. You can consider  date as YYYY-MM-DD format

In example data total sell qty=10. In desired output sell qty=15. Explain this or correct the data.

What version MySql is used?

@ValNik- I'm not concerned about the specific SQL type or version. I'm just looking for a SQL query that provides the expected output.

@ValNik - I’ve updated the example data. I previously made a mistake, which caused the discrepancy in the sell quantity. The question has now been updated accordingly.

If you don't have a particular server you want to run this query on, why do you want to know the answer?   Different database servers have different capabilities, there are almost no questions where those differences are irrelevant

You can match purchases and sales as segments of running total amounts of purchases and sales.
with your new test data
Buy(id)  1111111111333444444444444444
         |   |    |  | |            |
Sale(id) 222225555555555

See example



Date
id
ticker
txn_type
qty
price_per_share




2024-01-01
1
ABC
Buy
10
100


2024-01-02
2
ABC
Sell
5
105


2024-01-03
3
ABC
Buy
3
90


2024-01-04
4
ABC
Buy
15
85


2024-01-05
5
ABC
Sell
6
103


2024-01-16
16
XYZ
Buy
5
100


2024-01-17
17
XYZ
Buy
6
110


2024-01-18
18
XYZ
Buy
7
120


2024-01-19
19
XYZ
Sell
17
119


2024-01-20
20
XYZ
Buy
3
117



with buys as(
select id,ticker,date,txn_type,qty,price_per_share
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by ticker order by date)-qty+1 bfrom
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by ticker order by date)bto
from transactions
where txn_type='Buy'
)
,sells as(
select id,ticker,date,txn_type,qty,price_per_share
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by ticker order by date)-qty+1 sfrom
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by ticker order by date)sto
from transactions
where txn_type='Sell'
)
select b.ticker,b.id b_id, b.date buy_dt,b.txn_type bt,b.qty b_qty, b.price_per_share b_price
  ,s.id s_id,s.date sell_dt, s.txn_type st,s.qty s_qty,s.price_per_share s_price
  ,least(bto,sto)
   -greatest(bfrom,sfrom)+1 sell_qty
  ,bfrom,bto    
  ,sfrom,sto
  ,greatest(bfrom,sfrom) bi
  ,least(bto,sto) ei
from buys b
left join sells s on s.ticker=b.ticker
  and (  s.sfrom between b.bfrom and b.bto
      or s.sto between b.bfrom and b.bto
      or b.bfrom between s.sfrom and s.sto
    )
;




ticker
b_id
buy_dt
bt
b_qty
b_price
s_id
sell_dt
st
s_qty
s_price
sell_qty
bfrom
bto
sfrom
sto
bi
ei




ABC
1
2024-01-01
Buy
10
100
2
2024-01-02
Sell
5
105
5
1
10
1
5
1
5


ABC
1
2024-01-01
Buy
10
100
5
2024-01-05
Sell
6
103
5
1
10
6
11
6
10


ABC
3
2024-01-03
Buy
3
90
5
2024-01-05
Sell
6
103
1
11
13
6
11
11
11


ABC
4
2024-01-04
Buy
15
85
null
null
null
null
null
null
14
28
null
null
null
null


XYZ
16
2024-01-16
Buy
5
100
19
2024-01-19
Sell
17
119
5
1
5
1
17
1
5


XYZ
17
2024-01-17
Buy
6
110
19
2024-01-19
Sell
17
119
6
6
11
1
17
6
11


XYZ
18
2024-01-18
Buy
7
120
19
2024-01-19
Sell
17
119
6
12
18
1
17
12
17


XYZ
20
2024-01-20
Buy
3
117
null
null
null
null
null
null
19
21
null
null
null
null



fiddle
Work example without intermediate calculation results. Rows for range intersection cases test added to test data.



Date
id
ticker
txn_type
qty
price_per_share




2024-01-01
1
ABC
Buy
10
100


2024-01-02
2
ABC
Sell
5
105


2024-01-03
3
ABC
Buy
3
90


2024-01-04
4
ABC
Buy
15
85


2024-01-05
5
ABC
Sell
6
103


2024-01-16
16
XYZ
Buy
5
100


2024-01-17
17
XYZ
Buy
6
110


2024-01-18
18
XYZ
Buy
7
120


2024-01-19
19
XYZ
Sell
17
119


2024-01-20
20
XYZ
Buy
3
117


2024-01-01
101
ABCN
Buy
10
100


2024-01-02
102
ABCN
Sell
5
105


2024-01-03
103
ABCN
Buy
3
90


2024-01-04
104
ABCN
Buy
15
85


2024-01-05
105
ABCN
Sell
10
103


2024-01-01
201
ABCO1
Buy
20
100


2024-01-02
202
ABCO1
Sell
5
105


2024-01-03
203
ABCO1
Sell
3
90


2024-01-04
204
ABCO1
Buy
15
85



with rollamt as(
select id,ticker,date,txn_type,qty,price_per_share
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by ticker,txn_type order by date)-qty+1 bi
  ,sum(qty)over(partition by ticker,txn_type order by date)ei
from transactions
)
select b.ticker,b.id buy_id, b.date buy_dt, b.price_per_share b_price
  ,s.id sell_id,s.date sell_dt,s.price_per_share s_price
  ,least(b.ei,s.ei)
   -greatest(b.bi,s.bi)+1 sell_qty
from rollamt b
left join rollamt s on s.ticker=b.ticker 
  and (  s.bi between b.bi and b.ei
      or s.ei between b.bi and b.ei
      or b.bi between s.bi and s.ei
    )
where b.txn_type='Buy' and s.txn_type='Sell'   
;





ticker
buy_id
buy_dt
b_price
sell_id
sell_dt
s_price
sell_qty




ABC
1
2024-01-01
100
2
2024-01-02
105
5


ABC
1
2024-01-01
100
5
2024-01-05
103
5


ABC
3
2024-01-03
90
5
2024-01-05
103
1


ABCN
101
2024-01-01
100
102
2024-01-02
105
5


ABCN
101
2024-01-01
100
105
2024-01-05
103
5


ABCN
103
2024-01-03
90
105
2024-01-05
103
3


ABCN
104
2024-01-04
85
105
2024-01-05
103
2


ABCO1
201
2024-01-01
100
202
2024-01-02
105
5


ABCO1
201
2024-01-01
100
203
2024-01-03
90
3


XYZ
16
2024-01-16
100
19
2024-01-19
119
5


XYZ
17
2024-01-17
110
19
2024-01-19
119
6


XYZ
18
2024-01-18
120
19
2024-01-19
119
6



fiddle

Could you help me to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78941201/how-to-implement-fifo-matching-for-buy-and-sell-transactions-in-sql-considering also?

The above answer contains several +1/-1 adjustments that are not really necessary. They may make sense for discrete integer share quantities, but not for fractional share quantities (common in the trading world). I recommend removing the +1/-1 adjustments from the bfrom, sfrom, and sqty calculations. The first buy quantity (10) is now 0..10 instead of 1..10, the second buy quantity (3) is now 10..13 instead of 11..13, etc. I also recommend simplifying the range overlap check to a standard start1 < end2 AND start2 < end1 test. See this db<>fiddle.

@TN, thank you for comment and explanation. In share trading (price_per_share) usually integer share quantities. Moreover, lot of shares are usually traded. A lot can contain 1, 10, 100 or another integer number of shares.  Perhaps your note about non-whole lots is applicable to commodity trading.  As for prices in transactions, there is no doubt that these are decimal numbers or correct fractions - here your comments on rounding and the order of calculations are completely timely and interesting.

I used a more sophisticated segment intersection check for greater clarity. The condition you have given is, of course, much more elegant. Thank you.

Quick follow-up on the fractional share example. I tweaked the data in this fiddle so that it now includes a case where the discrete vs continuous range calculations produce different results. The continuous range query includes a sqty = 0.5 row that is absent from the discrete range query. (I am not sure if fractional share transactions are common for regular stocks, but they are common in mutual funds, and perhaps other derivative investment types.)

I agree with the difference you indicated. Perhaps the decimal numbers model is more general and should be applied in accounting. As a rule, integers are used in trade accounting.

I know of only 1 case where a non-integer number of shares appear. For example, if an 8:1 backsplit occurred, and there were 10 shares in the portfolio, then 1.25 shares will remain. Securities are traded in lots on the stock exchange. In this case, the minimum lot or an incomplete lot can only be an entire unit of paper. Therefore, the fractional part cannot be sold at trade markets. Fractional parts can only be sold on the over-the-counter market. The broker buys fractional parts of securities from clients, consolidates them into whole shares and can already enter to stock exchange.
